# Калькулятор Kivy: как запретить ввод одинаковых знаков

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.5, kivy

Есть код на Kivy:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.config import Config
from kivy.uix.label import Label

Config.set('graphics','resizable','0')
Config.set('graphics','width','400')
Config.set('graphics','height','450')


class Calculator(App):
    def calculat_e(self,instance):
        self.lbl.text = str(eval(self.lbl.text))
        self.formula = ''

    def update_label(self):
            if self.formula != '+' and self.formula != '*' and self.formula != '-' and self.formula != '.' :
                # if '*' in mas:    
                self.lbl.text  = self.formula

    def add_number(self,instance):
        if self.formula == '0' :
            self.formula = ''
        if self.formula == '+':
            self.formula = ''
        if self.formula == '-':
            self.formula = ''
        if self.formula == '*':
            self.formula = ''
        if self.formula == '.':
            self.formula = ''
        # if self.lbl.text[len(self.lbl.text)-1] != '**':
        if len(self.lbl.text) != 13:
            self.formula += str(instance.text)
            self.update_label()

    def clear_(self,instance):
        self.lbl.text = '0'
        self.formula = ''

    def build(self):

        self.formula = "0"

        bl = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        gl = GridLayout(cols=4,spacing=3,padding=[10])
        self.lbl = (Label(text='0',font_size= 50,size_hint=[1,.35],text_size=(400-20,450 * .35 -20 ),halign='right',valign='center'))
        bl.add_widget(self.lbl)
        gl.add_widget(Button(text='7',on_press= self.add_number))
        gl.add_widget(Button(text='8',on_press= self.add_number))
        gl.add_widget(Button(text='9',on_press= self.add_number))
        gl.add_widget(Button(text='*',background_color=[0,0,1,1],on_press= self.add_number))
        gl.add_widget(Button(text='4',on_press= self.add_number))
        gl.add_widget(Button(text='5',on_press= self.add_number))
        gl.add_widget(Button(text='6',on_press= self.add_number))
        gl.add_widget(Button(text='-',background_color=[0,0,1,1],on_press= self.add_number))

        gl.add_widget(Button(text='1',on_press= self.add_number))
        gl.add_widget(Button(text='2',on_press= self.add_number))
        gl.add_widget(Button(text='3',on_press= self.add_number))
        gl.add_widget(Button(text='+',background_color=[0,0,1,1],on_press= self.add_number))
        gl.add_widget(Button(text='C',on_press=self.clear_,background_color=[0,1,1,1]))
        gl.add_widget(Button(text='0',on_press= self.add_number))
        gl.add_widget(Button(text='.',on_press= self.add_number))
        gl.add_widget(Button(text='=',background_color=[0,0,1,1],on_press = self.calculat_e))

        bl.add_widget(gl)
        return bl

Calculator().run()
```

Это мой первый калькулятор на Kivy.Но никак не могу придумать как запретить ввод одинаковых знаков (+,-,*), т.е,чтобы не было 4+++++++4 или 3..............5,уже 2 день мучаюсь,подскажите кто знает.**Очень прошу указывать куда нужно добавлять код**

Answer (score -2):

Всякие "левые" фреймворки - это не для новичков-самоучек. Хотите писать под Android - осваивайте Java. От того, что вы уже знаете синтаксис Python, вам легче не будет, зато будет (гораздо) тяжелее по другим причинам.

Хотя, тут больше задача на алгоритмы, чем API, но вы этим еще дополнительно усложняете.

Скорее всего, нужно в add_number добавить проверку типа:

```
if self.formula.contains("+"):
    return
```

И так для каждого из знаков, комбинируя проверки, чтобы защититься не только от "2+++..." или "2+2+...", но и от "2+-...".

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75403/discussion-on-answer-by-sminc--kivy-----).